# Using Hasse-Minkowski

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

Given a quadratic form over $\mathbb Z$, how do I determine for which primes $p$ (including the infinite prime) I need to use to find a solution in $\mathbb Q_p$ in order to produce a global solution using Hasse-Minkowski? Every summary I have read says that this procedure involves only finite computation (checking primes dividing numerators/denominators of coefficients if the quadratic form is diagonalized), but this is never justified. Why is this true?

Closely related, how do we actually find the solutions for these primes? I have never seen an algorithm or suggestion to compute or determine the existence of real solutions, and for $p$-adic solutions, the best explanation I have come across amounts to "use Hensel to find a solution mod $p$ first (which makes perfect sense), and use Quadratic Reciprocity to find the solution mod $p$." How does the Quadratic Reciprocity step look when there is more than one variable involved?

In summary, which primes do we need to check, and why? What is a sketch of the mod $p$ algorithm using Quadratic Reciprocity? Is there a generic algorithm or algorithms for finding real solutions?

For future readers of this post, I should also ask for sources should one consult to find more detailed answers to these questions and/or for further reading.

Comment: For the real solutions it's pretty easy: if the form is definite positive (resp. negative) then there is a solution iff the value is positive (resp. negative), and if the form is nondefinite there is always a solution.

Comment: You have not specified a dimension. Try Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. Also, chapter 7 of Mordell, Diophantine Equations; his Theorem 4 on page 47 is something I have tried to explain on this site many times.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It seems that the background I might be missing here can be found in a dedicated reference on quadratic forms.

Comment: @CaptainLama What is meant by "value" here?